# I'm trying to create a function that reads CSV files without the CSV module, but am encountering a formatting error

Tags: python, string, csv, formatting

As a means of practicing formatting, I'm trying to format a CSV file into interpretable lists without the CSV module. The code I have written so far is as follows:

```
def formatting(filename):
"""Format the data in interpretable lists"""
data = [] #defining the list of data

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        i = 0
        while line[i] != ' ':
            temp = [] #defining placeholder list for line data to be stored in
            strip = '' #defining placeholder list element
            while line[i] != ',': #filling placeholder list element
                strip[i] += line[i]
                i += 1
            temp.append(strip)
        data.append(temp)
```

From which I encounter an indexing error:

```
strip[i] += line(i)
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I'm not certain why this doesn't work. I'm assuming it must be because strip starts empty and thus does not really have an index to begin with, so what I'd rather code is a function similar to that of appending lists (simply: append the i'th letter of line to the strip string). Some help would be very welcome! :)

Comment: `strip = ''` this is zero length string so this `strip[i]` will not work. Update your post with sample input and expected output

Comment: `split` the `line` variable with `delimiter`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a starting point to get what you want?

```
def formatting(filename):
    """Format the data in interpretable lists"""
    data = []  # defining the list of data
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(line.strip().split(','))
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of `strip[i]` where `strip` is an empty string and `i` is 0.

In your current logic of iterating through characters, there are some corrections to be done, especially on how to detect end of line and where should temp be initialized with empty list, to make this work. Please refer below code.

```py
def formatting(filename):
    """Format the data in interpretable lists"""
    data = [] #defining the list of data

    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip()!='':
                i = 0
                temp = [] #defining placeholder list for line data to be stored in
                while i<len(line):
                    strip = '' #defining placeholder list element
                    while i<len(line) and line[i] not in  [',','\n']: #filling placeholder list element
                        strip += line[i]
                        i += 1
                    temp.append(strip)
                    i+=1
                data.append(temp)
    return data
    
print(formatting("test.csv"))
```

If you may require an alternate without csv module, try below code.
This does the same as above code, but instead of going char by char, uses `split()` function.

```py
def formatting(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        return [line.split(",") for line in f.read().splitlines() if line]
    
print(formatting("test.csv"))
```